# label not showing after implement gradient color at view xcode

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, cagradientlayer

my labels don't show after I implement this gradient

```
gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.myview.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(displayP3Red:0.04, green:0.47, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0).cgColor, UIColor.init(displayP3Red:0.00 ,green:0.80, blue:0.67 ,alpha:1.0).cgColor]
self.myview.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: `self.myview.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code displays `UILabel` with `CAGradientLayer` ,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let GradientLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        GradientLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        self.view.addSubview(GradientLabel)

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = GradientLabel.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(displayP3Red:0.04, green:0.47, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0).cgColor, UIColor.init(displayP3Red:0.00 ,green:0.80, blue:0.67 ,alpha:1.0).cgColor]
        GradientLabel.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    }
```